# ASP.NET : An Unexpected network error while manipulating files on a remote storage

Tags: c#, asp.net, wic

I have an ASP.NET web application (C#) that splits tiff files on a remote NAS storage using WIC (Windows Imaging Component).

here is the code used for splitting, which is taken from this page:
[Speed up Tiff file processing with Microsoft Windows Imaging Components (WIC)](https://sharepointfieldnotes.blogspot.com/2013/07/speed-up-tiff-file-processing-with.html#comment-form)

```
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

public static void SPlitTiffWIC(string fileName)
{

    TiffBitmapEncoder newFileEncoder = null;

    FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(fileName);
    using (Stream documentStream = fi.OpenRead())
    {

        TiffBitmapDecoder originalFileDecoder = 
        new TiffBitmapDecoder(documentStream,
            BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat,  
            BitmapCacheOption.None);

        foreach (BitmapFrame frame in originalFileDecoder.Frames)
        {
            newFileEncoder = new TiffBitmapEncoder();
            newFileEncoder.Frames.Add(frame);
            using (FileStream stream = File.Create("c:\\tiffs\\"  
                          + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".tiff"))
            {
                newFileEncoder.Save(stream);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I am using  [UNCAccessWithCredentials](https://github.com/Santhoshattillid/BethesdaConsentForms/blob/master/BethesdaConsentFormWCFSvc/UNCAccessWithCredentials.cs) class to access the storage with required credentials.

I tested the code several times on the same files in the same location. Code works great most of the time, but sometimes it fails on random files at a random frame of the tiff file, with the following exception:

```
An unexpected network error occurred. 
at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath) 
at System.IO.FileStream.WriteCore(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count) 
at System.IO.FileStream.FlushWrite(Boolean calledFromFinalizer) 
at System.IO.FileStream.Dispose(Boolean disposing) 
at System.IO.Stream.Close() at System.IO.Stream.Dispose() 
at TiffManager.Split(String inputFilePath, String outPutDirectory) 
at transdocs.PopulateImages(Int32 trsh_num, String trsh_date)
```

I googled for this exception, but it seems to be something related to the storage! I just don't know! and I need your help considering the reason for this exception and how to handle it...
thanks in advance

Comment: Make sure your files are accessible to the user you are using.

Comment: i am sure they are accessible because during testing, the code worked for the same files in the locations many times.. exception occurs randomly, for random files (that previously worked), and random frames..

Comment: Since Code and Stackframe don't match, it's difficult to assert anything. This does look like a network error though (unrelated to Wic). Note that you're using WPF, not Wic (even if undercover WPF uses Wic, it's not exactly the same game as WPF itself is not supported on ASP.NET either while Wic is, but Wic is a native unmanaged component)

Comment: If this is really a random network error when accessing the remote files I would suggest to implement a retry strategy. Just assume this file processing failed and do a fix number of retries. If the frequency of the network fails is low enough this can be an acceptable solution. But only if you don't find out another better explanation for the real cause of the network error. Perhaps the stream is being disposed before it is completely flushed?

Comment: Try doing explicit `Flush` and `Close` of the file stream after the `Save`.

Comment: isn't the file stream implicitly flushed when the using block ends?
if not.. then, should i remove the using block in order to do the explicit flush?

Comment: in case i use explicit flush and close, how can i make sure that the statement :  
 newFileEncoder.Save(stream); 
 has finished saving before the flush is executed?